# What does my computer do if it receives a data-packet with a wrong checksum?

Tags: ip, checksum

Since modern routers don't check the header-checksum any more to increase performance I'm wondering what my computer is doing with defective data-packets?

Further reading links appreciated.

Comment: It discards bad packets, and as posted below by BloodPhilia, it requests the same packet again and again until it gets a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requests the data packet again. Wikipedia has a nice article that explains the workings of the TCP (Transmission Control Protocol). This protocol makes sure that lost (or damaged) data packages are intercepted and a packet repeat is then requested.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Data_transfer